# Multiple functions using array_map

Tags: php, arrays, function, array-map

`array_map` accepts string as its first argument. Is there a way, to use arrays instead of strings, like:

```
.... array_map( array('trim','urlencode'), $my_array);
```

so I could attach multiple functions.

Comment: *"`array_map` accepts string"* -- The first argument of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). There are 6 types of callables in PHP (see the examples on the documentation), you can easily find one that matches your project and coding style.

Comment: One way might be to:

`return array_map('trim', array_map('urlencode', $targets));`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can define a function to combine these `trim` and `urlencode` functions. Then use the new function name or the new function as the first parameter of the `array_map()` function.

```
array_map(function($v){
  $v = trim($v);
  $v = urlencode($v);
  return $v
}, $array);
```

Comment: for those who not so familar with PHP but wanna learn. `$v` is now the pointer, and `//trim() call // ur....` is ment as `$v = trim($v); $v = urlencode($v); return $v;`

Comment: should be ```return $v;```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way also. Reference: [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

> **Warning:** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this
>   function is highly discouraged.

[**Try this here code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794666)

```
$newfunc = create_function('$value', 'return urlencode(trim($value));');
$array=array_map($newfunc, $array);
```

Comment: Warning: create_function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged (from the docs your link points to)   :-)

Comment: $newfunc = function($value) { return urlencode(trim($value)); };